Visual Studio Debugger logs caught Exceptions and slow down Process
Currently I am experiencing long wait times due to a loop which iterates +10000 objects (strings to be exact). In this loop an operation occurs, which may throw an ArgumentOutOfRange. This is caught by an tryCatch block.
The code works fine and as expected. However, if I try to set a breakpoint after the loop, the debugger takes ages to get there, due to the Output-Console logging all of these errors and slowing down a lot. If I remove the catch block and just pass valid strings (same amount, however only valid values), the debugger is as "fast" as expected.
TL;DR
Is there a possibility to tell the Debugger to NOT print caught exceptions? Why does it get so much slower?

As a general rule, I would try to avoid using exceptions for non-exceptional failures. For invalid strings or other input validation it might be better to return an error code or some kind of result object instead.
